# Give player experience

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to code in Spigot when a player enchants they get half experience back. So whatever level they are they will get xp to make them half way to the next level.

I tried using `player.setExp(50);` but that doesn't work and sometimes it creates a second xp bar off to the side and seems glitched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the API, emphasis mine:

> *void setExp​(float exp)*
>
> Sets the players current experience points towards the next level
>
> **This is a percentage value. 0 is "no progress" and 1 is "next level".**
>
> Parameters:
>       exp - New experience points

So, if you want to set a player to half a levels experience then use: `player.setExp(0.5f);`

---

Edit to address the comment from Kerooker:

Your question is not very clear, but if you want to restore exactly half of the experience used when enchanting, then instead do it like this:

```
//On the enchantment event use this to find the total cost of the enchant:
int originalCost = event.getExpLevelCost();

//Now update the cost to be half of that and you are all done:
event.setExpLevelCost​(int originalCost / 2);
```

There are many many different ways to do this, for example, you could use `int totalEXP = player.getTotalExperience();` before the enchant, then use `player.giveExp​((totalEXP - player.getTotalExperience()) /2);` afterwards to give back exactly half of the experience used. Refer to both API links below.

---

Source:

https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html

https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/enchantment/EnchantItemEvent.html

Comment: @Kerooker The question is not very clear, but your point is good. I have updated my answer to consider levels and total player experience as well.

Comment: I am planning to have it so whatever level they currently are, they will gain half the experience needed to level up so if they already have halfway to the next level they will get another half and then level up.

Comment: @Dan Ahh, that's very easy, just use this to get the current exp and add an extra half level: `player.setExp(player.getExp() + 0.5f);`

Comment: Note, if using the code from my comment above, you may need to check if the total value is over 1, and do something different if you get the same bug with the exp bar.

Comment: What should I do if it's over 1 because right now it creates half of a second xp bar off to the side

Comment: @Dan I see you marked this as solved but to answer your last comment, you can use `player.setLevel(player.getLevel() + 1)​` to advance a player to the next level if the amount is more than 1, and then just use `player.setExp` to add the remaining experience that was more than 1.